# How to create a new Excel worksheet and create a given name in the VBA project

Tags: excel, vba

When you create a new worksheet, you can set the name with `.name = "Name Here!"` However, the VBA object will still have "Sheet1" as the name.

How do I create a new sheet and set the VBA object name?

Please note, I am not asking how to set the name as displayed on the workbook, nor the .name property.

Comment: You need to find the `VBComponent` from the `VBProject` associated with the document, and set its `CodeName` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Public Sub Change_Codename()

    Dim ws As Object

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws

        .Parent.VBProject.VBComponents(.CodeName) _
        .Properties("_CodeName") = "Test"

    End With

End Sub
```

Just change "Test" to whatever you want the sheet's code name to be.

Here is how my objects look after executing the code:

[image]

Also, make sure you have trusted access to the VBA project model by going to **File-->Options-->Trust Center-->Trust Center Settings...**. Under **Macro Settings** be sure to tick "Trust access to the VBA project object model", like so:

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, it's only the "Trust access to the VBA project object model" setting that is required.  This will work without the "Enable all macros" setting that's also shown in the screen-shot.

Comment: Follow-up question - is this setting workbook-specific, or user-specific?

Comment: The setting is at the application-level, so all workbooks you have open will obey these settings. If you are sending this code to run on another user's machine, they would also have to update this setting.